# How do i check if a specific Radio button is checked among the other radio buttons using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make javascript check if a specific Radio button is checked among the other radio buttons.

The validation method for checking if any radio button works perfectly:

This is a snippet the HTML code containing the radio buttons:

```
<form id = "buy" name = "buy" onsubmit = "return valiform()">

    <input type="radio" name="Card_type" value="visa" > Visa </input>
    <input type="radio" name="Card_type" value="mastercard" > Mastercard</input>
    <input type="radio" name="Card_type" value="paypal" > Paypal </input>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm order">
</form>
```

This is the snippet  of the Javascript code regarding the radio buttons:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
            function valiform(){
            var visa = document.buy.Card_type;
            var mastercard = document.buy.Card_type;
            var paypal = document.buy.Card_type;
            var message = "Error!\n";
            function validateRadio (radios)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < radios.length; ++ i)
                {
                    if (radios [i].checked) return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            if(validateRadio (document.buy.Card_type))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                message+= "Please select card.\n";
            }
            if(message != "Error!\n"){
            alert(message);
            return false;
            }
        }
 </script>
```

So far the code works perfectly, but I want the code to check if specifically the Paypal radio button is selected. I cannot do it without inducing an error. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the paypal line to:

```
<label><input id="paypalRadio" type="radio" name="Card_type" value="paypal"> Paypal </label>
```

This use this code which will return true if a given radio button is checked:

```
document.getElementById('paypalRadio').checked
```

or you could do this without changing anything:

```
$("td[name=Card_type]")[2].prop("checked", true)
```

Comment: Solved it with a similar approach to yours.

        if (document.buy.Card_type.value== "paypal")

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Radio inputs are empty elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning just `true`, you could have `validateRadio()` return the value of the checked button. Then you can assign this to a variable.

```
var selected = validateRadio(document.buy.Card_type);
if (selected == 'paypal') {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="radio" name="Card_type" value="visa" > Visa </input>` is invalid `html`; `<input>` is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element) , where content is not permitted. You can use `.addEventListener()`, `submit` event attached to `<form>` element, `.querySelectorAll()`, `Array.prototype.some()`, check the element at index `2` from result of `.querySelectorAll()` to determine if `input` element having `value` equal to `"paypal"` is checked

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="buy" name="buy">
    <input type="radio" name="Card_type" value="visa" />
    <input type="radio" name="Card_type" value="mastercard" />
    <input type="radio" name="Card_type" value="paypal" />
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm order">
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function valiform(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var radios = this.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]")
      var message = "Error!\n";

      function validateRadio(radios) {
        return Array.prototype.some.call(radios, function(input) {
          return input.checked
        })
      }
      if (validateRadio(radios)) {
        if (radios[2].checked) {
          alert(radios[2].value + " radio is checked")
        }
        event.target.submit();
      } else {
        message += "Please select card.\n";
      }
      if (message != "Error!\n") {
        alert(message);
        return false;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("buy").addEventListener("submit", valiform)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```